# How can we understand the true meaning of Khimar?

Tags: hijab

[Chapter 24 (Al-Nur), Verse 31](https://quran.com/24/31), talks about **khimar**.

When I read translations and tafsirs, I realize that there is a level of disagreement between scholars on this.

How can we make sure what **khimar** meant in the Arabia, in the days of Prophet?

What resources scholars use to understand this meaning?

Do we have wall paintings for this? Or do we have epigraphs or inscriptions related to **khimar**?
Or do we all go back to some books just written two or three centuries after Prophet?

Comment: What is the level of disagreement you are referring to? Perhaps the question would be better if you clarified

Comment: "...some books just written two or three centuries after Prophet" - How long after the Prophet was the book or the source that you used to make that claim written?

Answer (score -4):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AALgGKSnU2g

Salaam, watch the video. Hope it helps In sha Allah.

Comment: This video may contain an answer: This is a Q&A site therefore we expect the full answer to be displayed/written -in your own words- in the answer section simply sharing a link is not an answer as even evidences don't speak for themselves. See [answer] and see in [our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/are-link-only-answers-acceptable-here).